# Добавление сообщения + обновление страницы без перезагрузки

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, long-poll

Всем привет! Пишу модуль диалогов между пользователями, главная цель - после добавления сообщения не обновлять страницу, чтобы наш текст был сразу виден. Этакий аналог диалогов ВКонтакте.
Проблема в том, что не знаю, как это реализовать. Вроде как получилось сделать отправку сообщения без перезагрузки страницы, получаю console.log() с данными Response, но всё-таки, не получается двинуться дальше. И как можно реализовать обновление диалога? Буду признателен, если поможете с кодом.

**Контроллер**

```
public function sendMessage($id, SendMessageRequest $request)
{
    /**
     * TODO: Дополнить. Редирект, если диалог с самим собой
     */
    if ($id == Auth::id())
    {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    $conversation = Conversation::whereIn('user_one', [Auth::id(), $id])
        ->whereIn('user_two', [$id, Auth::id()])
        ->first(); // Получаем данные о беседе

    /**
     * Если диалога нет в базе - создаём
     */
    if ($conversation == NULL)
    {
        $newConversation = Conversation::create([
            'user_one' => Auth::id(),
            'user_two' => $id,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Добавляем сообщение
     */
    Message::create([
        'message' => $request->get('message'),
        'user_id' => Auth::id(),
        'conversation_id' => $conversation !== NULL ? $conversation->id : $newConversation->id,
    ]);

    $response = [
        'status' => 'success',
        'msg' => 'Setting created successfully',
    ];
    return Response::json($response);
}

/**
 * Переписка с юзером
 */
public function chat($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id); // Получаем данные юзера
    $title = 'Диалог с ' . $user->name . ' ' . $user->lastname; // Заголовок страницы

    /**
     * TODO: Дополнить. Редирект, если диалог с самим собой
     */
    if ($id == Auth::id())
    {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    $conversation = Conversation::whereIn('user_one', [Auth::id(), $id])
        ->whereIn('user_two', [$id, Auth::id()])
        ->first(); // Получаем данные диалога

    $messages = '';
    if ($conversation !== NULL)
    {
        $messages = Message::where('conversation_id', $conversation->id)->paginate(30); // Загружаем сообщения
    }

    return view('mails.chat', [
        'title' => $title,
        'conversation' => $conversation,
        'messages' => $messages,
        'user' => $user,
    ]);
}
```

**View**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

{{-- Самый примитивный вывод сообщений. Обновление, если есть новые сообщения в диалоги + обновление после добавления сообщения --}}
@if ($conversation !== NULL && count($messages) !== 0)
    @foreach($messages as $message)
        @php($sender = App\User::find($message->user_id))

        <div>
            <b>{{ $sender->name }} {{ $sender->lastname }}</b><br>
            {{ $message->message }}
        </div>
    @endforeach
@else
    <div class="alert alert-info">Нет сообщений.</div>
@endif

<form id="submit" method="post" action="{{ route('mails.sendMessage', $user->id) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <b>Сообщение</b><br>
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>

    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#id').on('submit',function(e){
            $.ajaxSetup({
                header:$('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            })
            e.preventDefault(e);

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:'{{ route('mails.sendMessage', $user->id) }}',
                data:$(this).serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(data){

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Мне когда-то очень помог разбор кода на github:
https://github.com/cmgmyr/laravel-messenger Надеюсь, что и Вам поможет! ))

Comment: Laravel, Vue, Realtime вот, целый плейлист, все подробно рассказывается https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jV7lVrtZVko&list=PLD5U-C5KK50X1KcfueA73sGSjBsd8vgVG

Answer (score 1):

После добавления сообщения в callback можете из контроллера передавать список сообщений, а на странице после удачного ajax запроса отправки сообщения нужно вывести список сообщений полученный из callback